# VerticalViewPager swipe vertically not horizontally

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, vertical-scrolling

I used this [library](https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager) to successfully get a vertical image slider which works just fine.  Only part I'm stuck on is being able to vertically swipe.  Right now I have to swipe horizontally to get my images to slide as seen [here](https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager/blob/master/art/zoom_out.gif) but i want to swipe vertically so it makes sense you know.  Thank you in advance for who ever can figure this out, I've looked everywhere :)

customSwipedapter.java

```
public class customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] images = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflator;

public customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view == (RelativeLayout)o);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
   }
}
```

mainActivity.java

```
public class savedImagesViewController extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
customSwipeAdapter adapter;
Bitmap bitmap ;
Thread thread ;
String evalue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_cards_view_controller);

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new customSwipeAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DefaultTransformer());
   }
}
```

mainActivity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.project_bc.project_bc.savedImagesViewController">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

swipe_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cardborder"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="onClick_FlipImage"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bcard1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this may help you !!  https://medium.com/@jimitpatel/viewpager-with-vertical-swiping-ability-e40200094281

Comment: Awesome I will try it and get back to you :)

Comment: Awesome, It worked.  Had to replace a bit of that code with some other code but overall your link helped me out a ton!!!

Comment: please click my comment as a helpful flag!!!!@A Parham

Comment: I’m fairly new to stack and not sure how to flag comments. :) care to tell me how and will most kindly do :)

Comment: please click like this above !!!

Comment: It is not allowing me ¿